# Error: Execution failed for task: processDebugResources

Tags: java, android

I get this message while building the app:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/d******p/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The thing is that I didnt change any code before getting this error, all I did was adding some pngs to my res folder. I took them out and the error persist.

I've found similar question on stackoverflow but none of the answers helped me.

What can I do?

Comment: Where you add the pngs? outside in res folder or inside another folder

Comment: put your build.gradle

Comment: If you have restored the code and resources back to a "good" state, but you still cannot build, try doing a clean build -- you may have some generated files that need to be cleaned out.

Comment: 1. The first one, you have to try to clean then build again.
2. The seconds you can check build.gradle again or .MK files that defined which resource has to build on.